# how to calculate composite metric in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Could you please advise how to calculate the variables A, B, C, D below ?
It is my 2nd day with pandas and I am having a difficulty finding the way to calculate them.

Here is my dataset :

```
d = [{'city':'new-york', 'code':1111, 'recv':1977.44, 'send':0.0},
{'city':'new-york', 'code':2222, 'recv':6758926663.7439995, 'send':0.0},
{'city':'new-york', 'code':3333, 'recv':189769.38666666666, 'send':0.0},
{'city':'amsterdam', 'code':4444, 'recv':2356311.024, 'send':263030.0906666667},
{'city':'amsterdam', 'code':5555, 'recv':959.968, 'send':8.063999999999998}]
```

Let's construct the dataframe :

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(d)
```

Grouping is important, the dataset is bigger, but for simplicity, we have 2 rows; 'city' and 'code'

```
In [35]: ixmac = df.groupby(['city','code']).sum().loc[:, ['recv','send']]
```

We have so many different cities in our dataset

```
In [36]: len(set(ixmac.index.get_level_values('city')))
Out[36]: 2
```

We have so many different codes in our dataset

```
In [37]: len(set(ixmac.index.get_level_values('code')))
Out[37]: 5
```

We have so many different codes in a specific city:

```
In [39]: len(set(ixmac.loc['new-york'].index.get_level_values('code')))
Out[39]: 3
```

Now, I would like to add a column to the dataframe ixmac using the assign method http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#assigning-new-columns-in-method-chains

`ratio_asn = A / B` where

```
A = len(set(ixmac.loc['new-york'].index.get_level_values('code')))
B = len(set(ixmac.index.get_level_values('code')))
```

but instead of specifying 'new-york' I would like this to be derived from the corresponding row automatically

and

```
ratio_recv = C / D
```

C is sth close `ixmac.query('city==["new-york"] & code==[1111]').loc[:,['recv']]`
but taking only the 'recv' number instead of the dataframe in question,
and 'new-york' and '1111' should be derived automatically from the corresponding rows and columns, in other words

```
In [52]: ixmac.query('city==["new-york"] & code==[1111]').loc[:,['recv']]
Out[52]: 
                  recv
city     code         
new-york 1111  1977.44

D = ixmac.query('city==["new-york"]').sum().loc['recv']
```

but instead of specifying 'new-york' I would like this to be derived from the corresponding row

The objective is to add 2 extra rows in the dataframe `ixmac` called `ration_asn` and `ratio_recv` and calculate every cell in these 2 columns based on the examples above.

Could you please advise/help to calculate A, B, C, D ?

**EDIT:** this is how the end result should look like:

```
                        recv           send ratio_asn   ratio_recv
city      code                             
amsterdam 4444  2.356311e+06  263030.090667 0.4 =2/5    0.00034849062450182164 =2.356311e+06/2.356311e+06
          5555  9.599680e+02       8.064000 0.4 =2/5    1.4197610070222678e-07 =9.599680e+02/2.356311e+06
new-york  1111  1.977440e+03       0.000000 0.6 =3/5    2.9245685332491435e-07 =1.977440e+03/2.356311e+06
          2222  6.758927e+09       0.000000 0.6 =3/5    0.9996230086742471 =6.758927e+09/2.356311e+06
          3333  1.897694e+05       0.000000 0.6 =3/5    2.8066268297069442e-05 =1.897694e+05/2.356311e+06

In [8]: total = 2.356311e+06 + 9.599680e+02 + 1.977440e+03 + 6.758927e+09 +1.897694e+05

In [9]: total
Out[9]: 2.356311e+06
```

Comment: Can you post your desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU thanks a lot for looking into it. I edited the original question with the requested info.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do it this way:

```
In [105]: g = df.groupby('city')

In [106]: df['ratio_asn'] = g.recv.transform(lambda x: len(x)/len(df))

In [107]: df['ratio_recv'] = g.recv.transform(lambda x: x/df.recv.sum())

In [108]: df
Out[108]:
        city  code          recv           send  ratio_asn    ratio_recv
0   new-york  1111  1.977440e+03       0.000000        0.6  2.924569e-07
1   new-york  2222  6.758927e+09       0.000000        0.6  9.996230e-01
2   new-york  3333  1.897694e+05       0.000000        0.6  2.806627e-05
3  amsterdam  4444  2.356311e+06  263030.090667        0.4  3.484906e-04
4  amsterdam  5555  9.599680e+02       8.064000        0.4  1.419761e-07
```

Comment: thanks a lot @MaxU, you understood correctly :) it works. may i ask you to help me and make it more generic; how it would like if we had multiple indices ? in other words, if the .groupby() had more terms ? "Grouping is important, the dataset is bigger, but for simplicity, we have 2 rows; 'city' and 'code'"

Comment: @NikosSkalis, i think i would need a sample data set and desired data set in order to provide you a solution...

Comment: I would like the 1st line to be like mentioned above `df.groupby(['city','code']).sum()`

Comment: and not like `df.groupby('city')`

Comment: ah thanks, but we assume that the same code cannot be present in multiple cities

Comment: i would prefer more generic than efficient, how it could be done ?